# Paralell computing opening and closing with calling parfor in MATLAB R2014a

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have a program that call a `m-file` that contains `parfor` for calculation. You know that in `MATLAB R2014a` we don't need open parallel computing using `parpool` or something likes that and `parfor` doing the same.

My question is about closing parallel computing. If i have this structure ( only `parfor` ) `MATLAB` closing `parallel computing` after ending process of `parfor`?  I'm calling this `parfor` every 10 seconds. I don't want `MATLAB` close the pool in every iteration of my system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`parpool`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parpool.html):

> If you set your parallel preferences to automatically create a
>   parallel pool when necessary, you do not need to explicitly call the
>   parpool command. **You might explicitly create a pool to control when
>   you incur the overhead time of setting it up**, so the pool is ready for
>   subsequent parallel language constructs.

It is true that we don't *have to* use `parpool`, but it makes sense to use it if you want to control the overhead it causes.

As for your question - take a look at the Parallel Computing Toolbox Preferences:

[image: How to make sure that the pool doesn't shut itself down spontaneously.]

I believe that the highlighted option is what was bothering you. If the default timeout is too short, you could either postpone it or disable it altogether.